# Вложенные запросы через связанные поля в django.db

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

В проекте имеются модели Семья (`Family`), Категория (`Category`) и Подкатегория (`Subcategory`):

```
class Family(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Trend(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, related_name='subcategories')
    families = models.ManyToManyField(Family, related_name='subcategories')
```

Таким образом структура БД выглядит так:

[image: Структура СУБД]

Получается, что во всей системе есть единые категория и подкатегории. При этом семьи могут для себя отключать подкатегории (если есть связь между `Family` и `Subcategory`, то значит подкатегория для семьи активна). Пытаюсь вывести все категории и подкатегории, добавив к подкатегориям дополнительный параметр `active`. На чистом `sql` запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT
  cat.*,
  subcat.*,
  CASE
  WHEN tr.id IN (
    SELECT tr.id
    FROM family fam
      INNER JOIN subcategoryfamilyrel rel ON fam.id = rel.family_id
      INNER JOIN subcategory subcat1 ON rel.trend_id = subcat1.id
    WHERE
      fam.id = {family.id}
  ) THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END AS active
FROM subcategory subcat
  INNER JOIN category cat ON subcat.category_id = cat.id;
```

Но при этом не могу понять, как правильно составить запрос через `ORM`. Дошел пока до того, что генерирую `queryset`, где классом модели выступает `Category`:

```
Subcategory.objects.annotate(
    active=Case(
        When(id__in=profile.family.subcategories.all().values('id'), then=True),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

И при передаче `queryset` в `rest_framework.Serializer` на выходе получается следующее:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Русский язык",
    "active": true,
    "area": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Школа",
      "color": "123456"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Математика",
    "active": ,
    "area": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Школа",
      "color": "123456"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Уборка",
    "active": true,
    "area": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Дом",
      "color": "ABCDEF"
    }
  }
]
```

А хотелось бы получать такое:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Школа",
    "color": "123456",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Русский язык",
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Математика",
        "active": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Дом",
    "color": "ABCDEF",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Уборка",
        "active": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Пока я вижу два решения:

1. Создавать запрос, отталкиваясь от `Category`, при этом в связанную `Subcategory` добавить поле `active`;
2. Существующий запрос с подкатегориями объединить под общими категориями.

Comment: Ничего понять не могу. Такое ощущение, что вы в таблицах запутались. Опишите лучше изначальную задачу.

Answer (score 0):

###### models.py

```python
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(
        to='Category', 
        related_name='subcategories', 
        blank=True, null=True, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

###### serializers.py

```python
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Category


class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Category
        fields=('id', 'name')


class RootCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subcategories = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_subcategories')

    class Meta:
        model=Category
        fields=('id', 'name', 'subcategories')
    
    def get_subcategories(self, obj):
        qs = obj.subcategories.all()
        return SubCategorySerializer(qs, many=True)
```

###### views.py

```python
from rest_framework import generics


class CategoryView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RootCategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.filter(parent_category=None)
```

Если ничего не забыл, и правильно понял запрос, то как-то так должно работать.